# Multiple ggplot objects in list is altered in loop

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I am saving multiple ggplots to a list to be used in a subsequent multiplot. The plots are generated in a loop and appended to the list, however, after the loop all plot objects in the list are the same as the last plot of the loop. I have done the type of operation before, without any issues. Has anyone experienced the same, and solved the problem?

```
figList <- list()

aoinum <- 1
for (aoi in AOI_list){
    ...
    # prepare dataframe for plotting
    dat <- data.frame(...)

    fig <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=x, y=y,  fill=z, alpha=q)) +
        geom_bar(...)+ 
        ...

    figList[[aoi]] <- fig

    aoinum = aoinum + 1
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, please?

Comment: Some points: - What do you use aoinum variable for? - I would use a numeric index instead of the name of the variables or whatever `aoi` refers to. - The problemn could be in the "hidden" code, when you build dat.

Comment: It looks as if your plot is always the same, just with different data. If that’s the case, don’t make new plots, make the plot once and apply the different data to it: `lapply(list_of_data_frames, function (df) fig %+% df)`. In general, do not use a `for` loop to create a list by appending to it. This is inefficient and messy. Use list functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to make a list of plots in a for loop

```
#Define list
ggcluster<-list()

for (cluster in 1:nclusters){
  # Simple plot )geom_polygon in my case)
  ggcluster[[cluster]]<-ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon(data = datoshp.df, aes(long, lat, group = group)) 
}  

# Build multiplot panel (two columns)

pngname<-paste(output_path,"plot-name",".png",sep="")
png(pngname,width = 1000, height = 1000)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(ggcluster,list(ncol=2)))
dev.off()
```